# Does anyone know the meaning and what he makes?

Tags: splice

I don't know what this [0] in the mudarPosicao function, can someone explain it to me?

```
var array = ["CAIO", "ARIADNE", "LETICIA", "SOFIA", "ENRIQUE", "FRANCISCO", "CHICO"]

function mudarPosicao(arr, de, para) {
    arr.splice (para, 0, arr.splice(de, 1)[0]);
    return arr                             ^-this
}
array = mudarPosicao(array, 1, 0)

console.log(array)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an English-speaking forum. Please write everything in English only.

Comment: are you sure ? I think you saw it wrong

Comment: Completely sure, as you can see in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72733655/revisions) ;)

Answer (score 0):

`splice` returns an array, so you need to actually retrieve the value from it, hence the `[0]`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice